# Programmable resistor

Tags: measurement

How do I make a programmable resistor for testing purpose? For example, I want the value of the resistor follow a ramp wave: 0ohm --> increase by 10k each 1ms, until reach 1Mohn and restart

Comment: How much voltage across the resitor?  (Or, how much current through the resistor?  Or, how much power do you have to dissipate on the resistor?)  If these parameters are small enough, you can look into [digital potentiometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_potentiometer).

Comment: It's for a microcontroller project, so V is 3.3V and A is in the range of 100mA.

Comment: "_How do I make a programmable resistor for testing purpose?_" For testing what? What is the power supply? Can one side of the "resistor" be connected to ground?

Comment: Um.. Isn't \$0 \Omega\$ at 3.3V more than 100mA? Or is there an additional series resistance?

Comment: "In the range"!, and it's not a direct connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ I'm going to ignore the case of connecting 3.3V across 0 Ω.  I'm going to assume that there will always be sufficient resistance to prevent components from getting burned. ]

Probably, the easiest way to do this is to use a [digital potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_potentiometer).  If we look at what kinds of digital pots are [available](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/data-acquisition-digital-potentiometers/2556350), there ones 1 MΩ resistance and 128 taps.

Comment: Thanks. I meant 3.3V as the voltage source for the whole project, not the voltage across the resistor ...

Comment: Well what did you mean then? You didn't mean 0 Ω either, apparently. -1 for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make a 'programmable' potentiometer is to take a simple LED, and connect an LDR to it by using (black) isolation tape (shown by the dashed box below). Make sure no light except from the LED reaches the LDR.

The 100R resistor of the LED should be chosen so that the maximum brightness can be reached (depending on the type/forward voltage of the LED).
The type of LDR depends the range of the output resistance.

Also this way the two 'subcircuits' can be decoupled (like a kind of analog optocoupler).

Than by lighting the LED, the LDR will change resistance. It doesn't look professional, but for about 5 cents you have a programmable resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX10fL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(note the photodiode symbol is an LDR, but cannot find it in the circuit designer).